# Client Disconnect to Server - Java Socket Programming

Tags: java, sockets, client

i have a problem. i want to video stream to client. i successful to send first image, but i cant send second image to client. beacuse client is discconnect. why? How can i resolve it?

[client code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5hkV.jpg)

[server code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3aTd.jpg)

Comment: I think something wrong in your approach. Please specify what exactly you want to do?  
Add code to the question in code block instead of attaching the screenshot.

Comment: i resolved my problem.